# JWPlayer - Add Query Parameters to source requests

Tags: javascript, manifest, jwplayer, http-live-streaming

I have a HLS stream which I view via JWPlayer.

`https://test.test.com/test.m3u8`

This manifest file contains a list of all the different quality level manifests. I need JWPlayer to add a URL parameter to each of these quality manifest files.

For example in JWPlayer I call my main manifest file:

`https://test.test.com/test.m3u8`

This may return:

`https://test.test.com/low.m3u8
https://test.test.com/med.m3u8`

When JWPlayer tries to load either of the two quality level manifests I need a URL parameter of spc=TimeStamp added.

I couldn't find anything within JWPlayers documentation on how to do this.